# VBA Copying data from one table to another and rearranging columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have 99 columns in one table called `tbl_raw`. I need to copy 96 of those columns into another table with the same exact header names, but they are rearranged in a different order. What is the most efficient way to do this?

The only way I knew was:

`raw_data.Range("tbl_raw[EMPLOYEE]").Copy
processed_data.Range("tbl_processed[EMPLOYEE]").PasteSpecial`

However, this would take a lot of code (96 * 2 = 192 lines) and I wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way to do it.

I tried to use https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables, but I couldn't figure out a way to do it with that information either.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Loop through the ListObject("tbl_processed").HeaderRowRange to collect each matching column in ListObject("tbl_raw").HeaderRowRange. It isn't clear whether you are appending or replacing the data in tbl_processed.

Comment: I am replacing the data. The first thing I do is clear the contents of the table except for the first row of data since I might add some columns with some formulas.

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve your solution. I'm not the best with VBA, but have managed to create some scripts and have been learning by doing. Would it be something like: `If tbl_raw.HeaderRowRange = tbl_processed.HeaderRowRange THEN ... I'm not sure exactly how to dynamically approach that.

Comment: I would create a mapping table and 2 arrays.  Write your source values to the 1st array and then using a For  loop and the mapping table and map each field to it's new column in the 2nd array.  Once the 2nd array is populated, just write the value of the 2nd array to your new table.  It sounds complicated but it's actually pretty simple and will be screaming fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid dealing with copying ListObject columns and use a direct value transfer.

```
Option Explicit

Sub raw2processed()

    Dim lc As Long, mc As Variant, x As Variant
    Dim raw_data As Worksheet, processed_data As Worksheet
    Dim raw_tbl As ListObject, processed_tbl As ListObject

    Set raw_data = Worksheets("raw")
    Set processed_data = Worksheets("processed")
    Set raw_tbl = raw_data.ListObjects("tbl_raw")
    Set processed_tbl = processed_data.ListObjects("tbl_processed")

    With processed_tbl
        'clear target table
        On Error Resume Next
        .DataBodyRange.Clear
        .Resize .Range.Resize(raw_tbl.ListRows.Count + 1, .ListColumns.Count)
        On Error GoTo 0

        'loop through target header and collect columns from raw_tbl
        For lc = 1 To .ListColumns.Count
            Debug.Print .HeaderRowRange(lc)
            mc = Application.Match(.HeaderRowRange(lc), raw_tbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)
            If Not IsError(mc) Then
                x = raw_tbl.ListColumns(mc).DataBodyRange.Value
                .ListColumns(lc).DataBodyRange = x
            End If
        Next lc

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great! It was very fast too, much faster than the copy and paste. I have one issue where the columns are losing their format. I have values that are '001' and I need them to remain a string, but they are getting converted to a number. Is there anyway to preserve the formatting of the value when using the direct value transfer method?

I haven't even started to dissect your code to understand it. I hope I can ask some clarifying questions after I try to understand it in detail! I really appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic example of copying over all but some columns from one table to another:

```
Dim tbl1 As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject
Dim h As ListColumn

Set tbl1 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
Set tbl2 = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table2")

'loop over the headers from the source table
For Each h In tbl1.ListColumns
    'is the column name in the "excluded" list?
    If IsError(Application.Match(h.Name, Array("col10", "col11"), 0)) Then

        'ok to copy...
        h.DataBodyRange.Copy tbl2.ListColumns(h.Name).DataBodyRange(1)

    End If
Next h
```

Comment: I think I follow that. I tried to execute that code within my script, but I could not get it to work. I am assuming the `Application.Match` is what checks the name of column in tbl1. However, I don't see where it matches it against tbl2. I also don't understand the 'Array' function there.

`Dim h As ListColumn

For Each h In tbl_raw.ListColumns
    If IsError(Application.Match(h.Name, Array("col10", "col11"), 0)) Then
    h.DataBodyRange.Copy tbl_imd.ListColumns(h.Name).DataBodyRange(1)
    End If
Next h`

Thanks for the reply and any further help would be appreciated!

Comment: `Array()` just creates an array from the arguments - it's used since Match needs an array to look up against.  For the table 2 match, it assumes that the column names are the same, and `tbl2.ListColumns(h.Name).DataBodyRange(1)` give you the paste destination as the first cell in the Table2 column with header `h.Name`

Comment: I think the op wants to copy the columns where the headers match, not the ones that don't. There would also have to be 96 elements in your lookup array so it might be easier to use `tbl1.HeaderRowRange`.

Comment: I  think I understood what the OP was asking, and my array only needs the three "do not copy" headers...

Answer (score 1):

ForEach/For are the magic of working with arrays and collections.
There are ways to make the following code more efficient, but I think that may get in the way of understanding what is happening.
It has been about 6 months or so since I last worked with VBA, but I believe this should work. I suggest stepping through and watching your locals to see what is going on. If there are issues with variable assignments, there might need to be a 'Let' changed to a 'Set'.
Code follows:

```
'// PROBLEM:
'// Copy data from one list to a second list.
'// Both lists have the same column names and the same number of columns.
'// Copy data based on the column name.

'// Modify to return a custom source-destination association.
Private Function GetColumnTranslations(zLeftColumns As ListColumns, zRightColumns As ListColumns) As Variant
  Dim zReturn(,) As Variant
  ReDim zReturn(0 To zLeftColumns.Count As Long, 0 To 1 As Long)
  Dim zReturnOffset As Long '// Specifies what index we are working at during our ForEach interations.  

  Dim zLeftVar As Variant
  Dim zRightVar As Variant

  ForEach zLeftVar in zLeftColumns
    '// Go through each 'left' column to Find the first 'right' column that matches the name of the 'left' column.
    '// Only the first 'right' column with a matching name will be used. Issue is solved with another ForEach, but beyond forum question's scope.
    ForEach zRightVar in zRightColumns

      If zLeftVar.Name = zRightVar.Name Then

        '// Store the association and exit the nested ForEach.
        Let zReturn(zReturnOffset, 0) = zLeftVar.Range.Column '// Source.
        Let zReturn(zReturnOffset, 1) = zRightVar.Range.Column '// Destination.
        Let zReturnOffset = zReturnOffset + 1

        Exit ForEach
      End If
    Next zRightVar
  Next zLeftVar

  '// Assign return value.
  Let GetColumnTranslations = zReturn
End Function


'// Take each source row and copy the value to a new destination row.
'// New rows are added to the end of the destination list.
Public Sub CopyList(zSourceList As ListObject, zDestinationList As ListObject)
  Dim zColumnTranslations As Variant '// Will be 2-dimensional array.
  Dim zTranslationVar As Variant '// Will be array of 2 elements. 
  Let zColumnTranslations = GetColumnTranslations(zSourceList.Columns, zDestinationList.Columns)

  Dim zSourceRowVar As Variant '// Will translate to Range.
  Dim zDestinationRow As Range

  '// Every source row needs copied to a new row in destination.
  ForEach zSourceRowVar in zSourceList.Rows
    Set zDestinationRow = zDestinationList.Rows.Add.Range

    ForEach zTranslationVar in zColumnTranslations
      '// Value may copy formula.
      Let zDestinationRow(0,zTranslationVar(1)).Value = zSourceRowVar(0,zTranslationVar(0)).Value
    Next zTranslationVar
  Next zSourceRowVar
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I was working on this for a bit before the above posts.

Comment: That's great! I really appreciate the comments and the break down. I really am looking to learn as much as I can and that helps me a ton! I am going to start dissecting this code too and seeing how everything works. How would you say this solution is relative to the solution @user11198948 posted?

Comment: My code does not clear the destination table. My code adds rows as needed. I don't know if user11198948's code is faster (I don't have Microsoft Office at this time), but I coded mine to allow modifications and so you may understand what is happening (I am self-taught and recall the difficulties).

GetColumnTranslations allows you to return a custom associations array.

Comment: (I'm still learning this website.) To copy the formatting, try adding a line under the comment "Value may copy formula" => Let zDestinationRow(0,zTranslationVar(1)).Style = zSourceRowVar(0,zTranslationVar(0)).Style

Comment: Do you happen to have a good starting place to learn some of the best practices in VBA? I see you Dim and ReDim and use some syntax which I am not familiar with at all. I've been trying to go through and search for the things I don't know, which is a lot more than I thought!

Comment: Well, I learned using Microsoft Office 2003 Access with VBA, DAO, and the help files that came with it all. I had no Internet. This was back in 2014, around June/July. Took me 6 months to learn VBA from scratch, along with tables, reports, and queries. I was in prison at that time. ... All my coding is self-taught -- VBA and C#. The whole API for Office is kinda screwy in my opinion.

Comment: As far as a place to learn best practices... study what you need using "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/" as this is where I pulled the info from above. Comment everything so you -and others- can quick-read what it does, even if you are repeating it word-for-word. Keep things simple. Don't be afraid to break things apart when it gets complicated (like I did in the above solution). These are things I do.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a generalized version to copy multiple tables. If anyone needs the code here it is (based on user11198948's answer).

```
Private Sub CopyTable(SourceTbl As ListObject, TargetTbl As ListObject)
Dim lc As Long, mc As Variant, x As Variant

With TargetTbl
    ' Clear target table
    On Error Resume Next
    .DataBodyRange.Clear
    .Resize .Range.Resize(SourceTbl.ListRows.Count + 1, .ListColumns.Count)
    On Error GoTo 0
    '   Loop through target header and collect columns from source table
    For lc = 1 To .ListColumns.Count
        mc = Application.Match(.HeaderRowRange(lc), SourceTbl.HeaderRowRange, 0)
        If Not IsError(mc) Then
            x = SourceTbl.ListColumns(mc).DataBodyRange.Value
            .ListColumns(lc).DataBodyRange.Value = x
        End If
    Next lc
End With
End Sub
```